# How to give structure to PHP code that connects to a db

Tags: php, database, connection

I have a php page that requires a few queries from a database. So I have started writing down a few functions and I noticed I need to make sure that the connection is alive and it closes connection as the data retrieval is done. But it doesn't take a genius to figure this is not the smartest way to deal approach this problem:

```
function getConnection() {
//it connects
}

function killConection() {
//it closes connection
}

function getData() {
getConnection();
//it gets data
killConnection();
}

function getVeryImportantData() {
getConnection();
//it gets data
killConnection();
}

//... and so on ...
```

I surely don't want to establish a new database connection for each request I need to make, so I am wondering if there is a way to organize my code that will keep the connection alive while I need it, that will reconnect in case it is closed for any reason and disconnect when all the required operations are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

1. Create an application class, which is your actual page
2. Add a method to this class which initilizes the database connection and saves it to say `$this->databaseConnection` property, this way you may check at a later time is you already have a database connection.
3. The rest of the functions you mention can be set as methods of the application class.

This is a bit more complicated than a simple script, but I think it is worth a try. It will help you in planning your application the right way, it will also help in structuring your application properly.

Also, using PDO is good idea.

Let me know if you need help with this type of approach.

Comment: I am using PDO and I am more comfortable with the idea to let a class manage the PHP/MySQL interaction. Do you think my actual page could instantiate a my-app-class object and perform what's needed?

Comment: I am not familiar with the background of yor code or its structure, but disregarding those, sure, it can.

Comment: @haunted85: Search along for something called *lazy initialization*, should work very well with PDO.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is simple:

1. Only open a connection to the database if you need one (and one is not yet opened)
2. Only close the connection to the database if you know, you don't need an additional one.

That will result into processings that will only open the database connection if a database query is done.

The database connection - if not specifically closed - will get closed automatically after the script finishes.

Millions of websites use this principle and they more or less work! So I think it's not that bad.

Comment: It is not bad at all. That is mysql mechanism, which is optimized at its best and only in very rare cases should be used differently.

Comment: @EduárdMoldován: I can't upvote right now, otherwise I had upvoted your answer already because you give a more concrete example.